# NTPD segfaults on 12.04 LTS (64-bit)

Tags: 12.04, ntp

Fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Installed ntp, but starting the service only results in the following error:

```
grsec: Segmentation fault occurred at 0000000000000008 in /usr/sbin/ntpd[ntpd:28951] uid/euid:108/108 gid/egid:116/116, parent /sbin/init[init:1] uid/euid:0/0 gid/egid:0/0
```

I found https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/liblockfile/+bug/941968 and it appears to be generated by long host names (mine was 26 char, as generated by the hosting provider (`ns12345678ip-123-45-67.net` is an example).

I changed the hostname in `/etc/hosts` to something short and also ran hostname shortname, but still the same error.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.